# Existe alguma forma de conectar o Python a um Websocket como se fosse cliente?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Os navegadores modernos possui o objeto `Websocket`, que permite fazer uma conexão com um servidor Websocket, permitindo comunicação em tempo real.

A minha dúvida é a seguinte:

- Existe alguma biblioteca, em Python, que me permitiria conectar a um Websocket, recebendo e enviando os dados, como se fosse o navegador?
- Se não, é possível fazer uma implementação que me permita conectar a um servidor WebSocket?

Comment: Faz um tempo que não pego para brincar com ela, mas acho que a [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/) tem como fazer isso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, existe essa (deve existir mais, talvez enumere depois):

- https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/ (pip)
- https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client (repositório)

Instale via pip:

```
pip install websocket-client
```

Um exemplo de uso fornecido:

> **Nota:** `ws://echo.websocket.org/` é um serviço para testes

```
import websocket

try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread

import time

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    def run(*args):
        for i in range(3):
            time.sleep(1)
            ws.send("Hello %d" % i)
        time.sleep(1)
        ws.close()
        print("thread terminating...")
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://echo.websocket.org/",
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

Só pra constar um detalhe do código, creio que isto seja para compatibilidade entre Python2.7 e Python3:

```
try:
    import thread #python2, se falhar vai para o except
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread #python3 para python3
```

---

> Se não, é possível fazer uma implementação que me permita conectar a um servidor WebSocket?

Se uma lib pode fazer isso então sim, é possivel fazer manualmente esse processo, assim que possível você escrever explicando sobre o *handshake* para então poder dar uma explicação de como criar o seu próprio "cliente" para WebSockets.

> *Resposta em construção...*

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro a utilização do `aiohttp` pois é assíncrono e assim não precisa de threads:

```
async with session.ws_connect('ws://echo.websocket.org') as ws:
    await ws.send_str('Olá Websocket!')
    async for msg in ws:
        print('Recebi', msg.type, msg.data)
        if msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.TEXT:
            if msg.data == 'Olá Websocket!':
                await ws.close()
                break
            else:
                await ws.send_str(msg.data + '/answer')
        elif msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.ERROR:
            break
```